# How to use choice parameter value to trigger a specific maven build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I'm new to Jenkins/Build Engineering/Scripting.

I have a requirement in Jenkins job, where I have a choice parameter 'COMPONENT' with 3 values - A, B, C.

Based on the parameter selected when running the build, I need to write a shell script(? or any other way?) to point to that particular pom.xml and trigger the build among the 3.

How to do this in Jenkins? Any details will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the maven plugin for Jenkins supports the functionality you are looking for, but you can always use the script plugin to write a script to do what you are looking for.  You can have the script do the selection and run correct maven build.

Comment: Using the shell script option, something similar:
*********
$ echo $LOGNAME
buildeng
$ export $LOGNAME

if [ "$LOGNAME" == "buildeng" ] // THE MOST IMPORTANT THING IS THE SPACING BETWEEN THE SQUARE BRACKETS
then
echo "Pass"
exit
fi